# Getting null parameter value in controller when an MVC route fires

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

First off, I'm new to MVC, so please excuse the question if it's basic.

I'm using a custom route to create the following URL (http://mysite/subscriber/12345) where 12345 is the subscriber number. I want it to run the `ShowAll` action in the `Subscriber` controller. My route is firing and using [Phil's route debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx), when I pass in the above url, the route debugger shows ID as 12345. 
My controller is accepting an int as `subscriberID`. When it fires,
the controller throws the error

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32".

Why does the route debugger show a value and the controller doesn't see it?

Here's my route (first one is the culprit)

```
 routes.MapRoute(
              "SubscriberAll",
              "subscriber/{id}",
              new { controller = "Subscriber", action = "ShowAll", id=0 },
              new { id = @"\d+" } //confirm numeric
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

Any idea why I'm getting a null in the `ShowAll` action? Here is the action method signature:

```
 public ActionResult ShowAll(int id)
```

Comment: Can you post all route registrations allong with the action method signature?

Comment: I think the problem is with your constraint.  I'm not a regex ninja though so I can't help you there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found that the controller method signature needs to accept a string as MVC doesn't know what type the passing parameter is and therefore can't cast it to int, but it can enforce it through the constraint.

So, the route I ended up with is this:

> routes.MapRoute(
>                 "SubscriberAll",
>                 "subscriber/{id}",
>                 new {controller = "Subscriber", action = "ShowAll" },
>                 new {id = @"\d+" } //confirm numeric
>               );

and the controller method signature I ended up with is this

```
 public ActionResult ShowAll(string id)
```

Comment: That is not accurate; in fact, MVC tries to parse whatever string you pass in the url to int. Using public ActionResult ShowAll(string id) + new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } should work as long as the id parameter is of type int and called id, nothing else like personId.

Comment: @usefulBee: thanks for writing _"and called id, nothing else like personId"_, I just realized that I made this mistake in my code, and now I feel like an idiot, but my problem is solved! :D Thanks. I think you should post it as a separate answer (you'd at least get an upvote from me).

Comment: Omg, i had inadvertently changed the parameter name from id to a more specific one, and that broke routing.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing id from the list of defaults ie just have

```
new { controller = "Subscriber", action = "ShowAll" }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing "id = 0" in your MapRoute write "id = UrlParameter.Optional"

this would definitely work with your action result

```
public ActionResult ShowAll(int id)

routes.MapRoute(
                  "SubscriberAll",
                  "subscriber/{id}",
                  new { controller = "Subscriber", action = "ShowAll", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                  new { id = @"\d+" } //confirm numeric
                );
```